# Group and transpose dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

Trying to create a table where the headers are:

```
Date          FileName1 FileName2 FileName3
01-Jul-19       0%          0%        0%
02-Jul-19       0%          0%        0%
03-Jul-19       0%          0%        0%
04-Jul-19       0%          0%        0%
```

The raw data looks like this:

```py
x = [
['01/07/2019',  'JULY 2019-JULY 29, 2019.csv', '0%'],
['01/07/2019',  'JULY 2019-JULY 30, 2019.csv', '0%'],
['01/07/2019',  'JULY 2019-JULY 31, 2019.csv', '0%'],
['02/07/2019',  'JULY 2019-JULY 29, 2019.csv', '0%'],
['02/07/2019',  'JULY 2019-JULY 30, 2019.csv', '0%'],
['02/07/2019',  'JULY 2019-JULY 31, 2019.csv', '0%'],
['03/07/2019',  'JULY 2019-JULY 29, 2019.csv', '0%'],
['03/07/2019',  'JULY 2019-JULY 30, 2019.csv', '0%'],
['03/07/2019',  'JULY 2019-JULY 31, 2019.csv', '0%'],
['04/07/2019',  'JULY 2019-JULY 29, 2019.csv', '0%'],
['04/07/2019',  'JULY 2019-JULY 30, 2019.csv', '0%'],
['04/07/2019',  'JULY 2019-JULY 31, 2019.csv', '0%'],
['05/07/2019',  'JULY 2019-JULY 29, 2019.csv', '0%'],
['05/07/2019',  'JULY 2019-JULY 30, 2019.csv', '0%'],
['05/07/2019',  'JULY 2019-JULY 31, 2019.csv', '0%']
]
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=['Date','File Name','Occ%'])

Date                   File Name           Occ%
01/07/2019  JULY 2019-JULY 29, 2019.csv 0%
01/07/2019  JULY 2019-JULY 30, 2019.csv 0%
01/07/2019  JULY 2019-JULY 31, 2019.csv 0%
02/07/2019  JULY 2019-JULY 29, 2019.csv 0%
02/07/2019  JULY 2019-JULY 30, 2019.csv 0%
02/07/2019  JULY 2019-JULY 31, 2019.csv 0%
03/07/2019  JULY 2019-JULY 29, 2019.csv 0%
03/07/2019  JULY 2019-JULY 30, 2019.csv 0%
03/07/2019  JULY 2019-JULY 31, 2019.csv 0%
04/07/2019  JULY 2019-JULY 29, 2019.csv 0%
04/07/2019  JULY 2019-JULY 30, 2019.csv 0%
04/07/2019  JULY 2019-JULY 31, 2019.csv 0%
05/07/2019  JULY 2019-JULY 29, 2019.csv 0%
05/07/2019  JULY 2019-JULY 30, 2019.csv 0%
05/07/2019  JULY 2019-JULY 31, 2019.csv 0%
```

Tried running : `df.set_index(['Date']).T` and `.groupby('Date')['File Name']`.

[image: How the data looks like]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be looking for a [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) of your data, where you transpose the `File Name` column and have your values by `Occ%`.

```py
df.pivot('Date', 'File Name', 'Occ%')

Out[3]: 
File Name  JULY 2019-JULY 29, 2019.csv JULY 2019-JULY 30, 2019.csv  \
Date                                                                 
01/07/2019                          0%                          0%   
02/07/2019                          0%                          0%   
03/07/2019                          0%                          0%   
04/07/2019                          0%                          0%   
05/07/2019                          0%                          0%   

File Name  JULY 2019-JULY 31, 2019.csv  
Date                                    
01/07/2019                          0%  
02/07/2019                          0%  
03/07/2019                          0%  
04/07/2019                          0%  
05/07/2019                          0%
```